# How to fill an ArrayList<TextView> with data of another smaller List of Strings in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of TextViews of a fixed size X.

I want to set the text of the TextViews based on a smaller ArrayList of Strings.

The remaining ArrayList TextViews I want them to have e.g a dash

How I am going to accomplish this with following way?

```
for(int i = 0; i<TotalList.size();i++)
{
    TotalList.get(i).setText(SmallerList.get(a).toString());
    a++;       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// iterate over smaller list 
for(int i = 0; i < SmallerList.size(); i++) {
    TotalList.get(i).setText(SmallerList.get(i));    
}

// set remaining items
for (int i = SmallerList.size(); i < TotalList.size(); i++) {
    TotalList.get(i).setText("---");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < smallList.size(); i++) {
    totalList.get(i).setText(smallList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: The Smaller list is ArrayList<String> and the TotalList is TotalList<TextView>

Comment: @MiaoulisNikos sorry, misunderstood the question, fixed it

Comment: Thanks for your submission to StackOverflow!  Could you please add some text explanation for why this solves the problem?  This will help future readers who might experience the same, or similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
int size = smallerList.size();
for(int i = 0; i<TotalList.size();i++)
{
    TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    if(i <size){
        tv.get(i).setText(SmallerList.get(i).toString());
    }else{
        tv.get(i).setText("-"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<TotalList.size();i++){
    if(i < SmallerList.size()){
        TotalList.get(i).setText(SmallerList.get(i));
    }else{
        TotalList.get(i).setText("...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two for loops :

```
    for(int i = 0; i<SmallerList.size();i++)
    {
        TotalList.get(i).setText(SmallerList.get(i).toString());
    }

    for(int i = SmallerList.size(); i<TotalList.size();i++)
    {
        TotalList.get(i).setText("----------");      
    }
```